# Display column headings on multiple tables from different lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view in ASP.NET MVC that accesses a viewmodel with 2 separate lists.  The problem I am having is accessing the column headings from the lists to display them above each data set.  The foreach statements accurately display the data but currently I am using a foreach statement on the column headings as well (Display name for).  I need to modify this statement to access the list (NotesList) and to only display one iteration of them above the dataset shown in the td statements.  I appreciate your feedback.  The view is below.

```
@model Risk.ViewModel.ListCatViewModel
....
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model.NotesList)
    {
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.Category)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.CountOfLoans)</th>
            ....
        </tr>
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model.NotesList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountOfLoans)</td>
            ....
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: I got it to work by manually typing the column headings in each th html tag.  However, I am looking for an automated solution as if I change the class that ties to the sql server that will change the columns and then I would have to change each column heading in the view vs. having an automated solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your `<th>` elements using

```
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.NotesList.FirstOrDefault().Category)</th>
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.NotesList.FirstOrDefault().CountOfLoans)</th>
....
```

Note this works even of the `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null` (i.e. because the collection is empty) because `HtmlHelper` use values from the objects `ModelMetadata`

Side note: Recommend you header elements be wrapped in a `<thead>`